# Finding the maximum number of files in a subdirectory

Tags: bash, unix, subdirectory

so I'm trying to write a bash script that would look through all the subdirectories in a specified folder and would return the max number of files in a single subdirectory. Here is what I have right now:

```
#!/bin/bash   
maxCount=0 
fileCount=0 
# script that writes out all the directories and how many files are in each directory

find ./testdata/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do  #loop all subdirectories    
fileCount= find "$dir" -type f | wc -l #count all the files in subdirectory

    if [ $fileCount -gt $maxCount ] #if the count is higher than the max     
    then
        maxCount= "$fileCount" #set the count equal to the max
    fi

    done

#print out how many messages are in the thread    
echo "$maxCount"
```

First off, the variable fileCount is not setting properly. The output of find "$dir" -type f | wc -l is still being set to stdout and as such the script keeps returning zero.

Example of the current output:

```
1
1
2
1
1
1
0
```

Where the last zero is the output for echo "$maxCount"

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

*Using xfce4 terminal*

Comment: Since the `while` loop is executed in a new subshell, variables used inside will not be available once the loop terminates

Comment: @etopylight How would I be able to preserve the variable value then?

Comment: a simple workaround is to use **command grouping** which uses curly braces to make those commands and variables coexist under the same scope, for example `{while read dir; ... echo "$maxCount"}` should do the work

Comment: @etopylight When I tried doing that I got an error when running: "syntax error near unexpected token 'do' "

Comment: Sorry for the mistyped code, a correct example should be `{ while read dir; ... echo "$maxCount"; }`, notice the additional space needed between `{` and `while` and semicolon between the last command and `}`

Comment: @etopylight Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct formatting:

```
#!/bin/bash   
maxCount=0 
fileCount=0 
# script that writes out all the directories and how many files are in each directory

find ./testdata/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | { while read dir; do  #loop all subdirectories    
fileCount=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) #count all the files in subdirectory

    if [ $fileCount -gt $maxCount ] #if the count is higher than the max     
    then
        maxCount= "$fileCount" #set the count equal to the max
    fi

    done

#print out how many messages are in the thread    
echo "$maxCount"; }
```

### Changes:

```
fileCount=${find "$dir" -type f | wc -l}
```

Used [Command Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to properly set fileCount variable to correct value

```
{ while read dir; do ... echo "$maxCount"; }
```

Used [Command Grouping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/grouping_plain) to keep maxCount in the same scope as the while loop when echoing the result.

Hope this helps others in the future!

Comment: `fileCount=${find "$dir" -type f | wc -l}`? Are you sure it worked for you?

Comment: @codeforester Mistyped, should be parentheses instead.

Comment: Sorry, understood why my answer was wrong.  I have removed my downvotes.  And deleted my answer as well.  I had upvoted your well asked question earlier.  Peace!

Answer (score 4):

You could do what you want with the following command which takes advantage of the `find`'s `-exec` option

```
find ./testdata/  -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'find {} -type f | wc -l' \; | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

And as in your approach, this line

```
fileCount= find "$dir" -type f | wc -l #count all the files in subdirectory
```

there should be no space between `=` and `find` and you should have a [Command Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to assign the value to the variable `fileCount` like this:

```
fileCount=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
```

And if you want to be stick to the for loop:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir;do
    cnt=$(find ${dir} -type f | wc -l)
    echo ${cnt}   
done | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Command Substitution fixed the output problem, but the maxCount still isn't changing from 0

Comment: @etopylight commented explaining the reason why the variable isn't holding value

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a little more efficiently in pure Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# build a hash of directories and file counts
declare -A file_hash
while read -r -d '' file; do     # read the null delimited output of find
  dir="${file%%/*}"              # extract **top dirname** from file path
  ((file_hash[$dir]++))          # increment the count for this dir
done < <(find . -type f -print0) # find all files and output them with a null delimiter
                                 # this will gracefully handle files or directories that have new lines in their name

# find the top directory name with the biggest file count
max=0
for i in "${!file_hash[@]}"; do
  count="${file_hash[$i]}"
  ((count > max)) && { max=$count; max_dir=$i; }
done
printf 'max_dir=[%s], max_count=[%s]\n' "$max_dir" "$max"
```

In this approach, we do a single scan of the top level subdirectories with `find`.  This will do well when there are large number of directories.

Comment: That's not what my question was asking. If I wanted someone to do my work for me, I would have just asked that instead. Thanks for down voting my stuff because I didn't accept your answer.

Comment: Finally, found the right way to do it in pure Bash a single call to `find`.  The trick is to grab all the files (across all subdirectories) through `find` and then extract the top directory name from each path and use that as the hash key.